AUCTeX: disable indentation but keep filling
I want to disable indentation of a couple of specific environments in AUCTeX, but to keep the normal filling rules. Is this possible?
First I thought that LaTeX-indent-environment-list had something to do with it, but in the description of LaTeX-fill-region-as-paragraph it says:

You can disable filling inside a specific environment by adding it to
‘LaTeX-indent-environment-list’, only indentation is performed in that
case.

I want to do the opposite: disable indentation, only do filling.

Can you tell for which environments you want to change the behavior?

The refsection, for example.

AUCTeX provides a variable called LaTeX-document-regexp, from the docstring:

LaTeX-document-regexp is a variable defined in latex.el.
Its value is "document"
Regexp matching environments in which the indentation starts at col 0.

You can now use the custom interface to set this variable or put something like this in your init file:
(setopt LaTeX-document-regexp "document\\|refsection")

or
(use-package auctex
  :custom
  (LaTeX-document-regexp "document\\|refsection"))

depending on how you manage your changes.
